# No way to accept Itunes Connect Agreement Update

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm walking in circles trying to create a new app in Apple's Itunes Connect. Here are the steps I'm doing:

When I log in to Itunes Connect I'm seeing a screen asking me to "Review the iOS Developer Program License Agreement."

[image]

I click continue and then I'm presented with a "Manage Your Apps" screen.

[image]

I click Add New App and it sends me to... the Agreement Update again:

[image]

So I click on Members Center this time and it goes here:

[image]

Clicking on Itunes Connect sends me back to... yes, the Agreement Update once more.

How do I solve this issue? Where is the secret door to adding a new app?

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache and restart the browser.

Comment: That doesn't do it, @rmaddy

Comment: How about clearing cookies (at least for the apple.com domain).

Comment: So now when I come to "Confirm your App ID" and press "Continue" the screen hangs forever. Any advice, @rmaddy? I'm trying to avoid asking another question on these completely trivial issues.

Answer (score 10):

I got stuck here too - here's how it went for me:

1. Nothing showed up in [iTunesConnect's finance/agreement area](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contracts) at first *(... even though the links kept sending me there!)*
2. I eventually found something to view/accept at the top of the general [Apple Member Center](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action) home page.
3. After step 2, something new finally showed up in [iTunesConnect's finance/agreement area](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contracts) that I could accept

After above steps I was able to continue what I was trying to do in iTunesConnect which, in my case, was setting up some new promo codes for [my app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocketswatch/id509958461?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Tried clearing cookies and cache per above recommendations, nothing. Waited 20m, bingo. Looks like your contract acceptance has to go through some review process, whether manual or automatic, taking a bit of time. I imagine the cookies/cache-clearing having worked was simply you cleared at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Open the Link https://itunesconnect.apple.com from Laptop Not Mobile. It will ask you to Accept the Terms and condition. While you open the link from mobile the Accept option will not visible to you. So open the link from Laptop and Accept the terms and condition.

Answer (score 0):

***If you are already registered in TRACES, please login with your registered User Id (PAN), Password & PAN else register as new user*emphasized text**** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5etX.jpg)

Had the same problem. Tried clearing cookies and cache per above recommendations, nothing. Waited 20m, bingo. Looks like your contract acceptance has to go through some review process, whether manual or automatic, taking a bit of time. I imagine the cookies/cache-clearing having worked was simply you cleared at the right time.